# Capture keypress on Anchor Tag

Tags: html, tags

In our application we are using anchor tags for all our buttons:
  so that certain styles can be implemented.

Anchor Tag never gets focus while pressing tabs. 
We have onClick implemented, but how do I capture 'enter' keypress event?

We need to make sure, that OnClick, keeps working.

Comment: What is an anchor tag? <a name="anchor"></a> this?

Comment: I think anchor tag is here referred to that in `href`, right?

Answer (score -1):

Add tabindex for you anchor tags.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_tabindex.asp

Comment: I think he needs something like keydown or keypress. It would be needed if you need to do something in response to the user action. Tabindexes only let you focus the anchors via the Tab key, but they don't tell you when it is focused, clicked or a key is pressed on it.